# ubuntu: how to get installed softwares from other ubuntu machines using dpkg

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

I can able to get the installed softwares from my ubuntu machine using dpkg.
Trying to collect the information from corporate wide ubuntu machines.

how do i get installed softwares from other ubuntu machines using dpkg?

(like using windows powershell script get-wmi with computername option to get from other computers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
dpkg -l
```

or

```
apt --installed list
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file containing all the packages in your system with:

```
dpkg --get-selections | sed "s/.*deinstall//" | sed "s/install$//g" > pkglist
```

pkglist will contain all packages which are installed in your system. Then you can use this file to migrate to another ubuntu machine.

This [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111236/how-to-migrate-the-whole-system-to-a-new-machine) will probably help you more.